# How to handle global errors in forms in Play Framework 2 (Java)

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

When handling errors in forms in Play Framework 2 (Java), I want to present an overall error message that warns the user that something went wrong, e.g. "*Form X not updated*". One way to do this is, in addition to the errors for each form field, to create a global error, and then present this on each template:

Controller:

```
if(form.hasErrors()) {
    form.reject("Form X not updated."); // This creates a global error
}
```

Template:

```
@if(form.hasGlobalErrors) {
    @someFunctionToPresentErrors(from.globalError.message))
}
```

However, adding this identical piece of code to *each* template that contains a form violates the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

My best solution so far is to add the error message to `Http.Context` instead and then intercepting the error message in the main template that is called by each template:

Controller:

```
Http.Context.current().args.put("error", "Form X not updated.");
```

Main template:

```
@if(Http.Context.current().args.containsKey("error")){
    @someFunctionToPresentErrors(
        Http.Context.current().args.get("error").asInstanceOf[String])
}
```

This is better because it allows me to keep the error presentation stuff in one place, but it feels like abuse of `Http.Context`. Note that `flash(...)` can also be used to pass variables implicitly around and gives the same effect as `Http.Context`, but that this is not allowed when calling `badRequest(...)`, since flash should only be used for redirects. In any case, I am thinking there should be a better way to do this using the form machinery provided by Play Framework.

Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 4):

I think you overvalue the *DRY violation* in this case - actually I realized that even *global* error isn't so global - actually every form has it's own context. Anyway to make work faster you can make usage from [**template tags**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplateUseCases#Tags-(they-are-just-functions-right?)) and [**Flash scope**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaSessionFlash#Flash-scope)

First add two generic public methods i.e in your `Application` controller

```
public static void flashGlobalError() {
    flashGlobalError("Oppps... error occurred and I don't know the reason ;(");
}

public static void flashGlobalError(String msg) {
    flash("globalError", msg);
}
```

then create a parameterless [**tag template**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplateUseCases#Tags-(they-are-just-functions-right?)) i.e. `views/tags/globalErrorByFlash.scala.html`

```
@if(flash.get("globalError")) {
    <div style="background: red">
        <h4>Error!</h4>
        @flash.get("globalError")
    </div>
}
```

and include it in your `main` template (or within selected views only) as:

```
<body>
    @tags.globalErrorByFlash()
    @content
</body>
```

So every time when you want to display this error you can just do it in your action:

```
if(form.hasErrors()) {
    Application.flashGlobalError();
    return badRequest(...);
}
```

or

```
if(form.hasErrors()) {
    Application.flashGlobalError("This case is quite bit different...");
    return badRequest(...);
}
```

The best benefit from this approach is that you don't need to depend on `Form.form(T)` as you can use it anywhere:

```
if (1 != 0){
    Application.flashGlobalError("Stupido! One isn't equal to Zero!");
}
```

**Finally**: keep in mind that any value kept in flash scope *lives* just for one request, so it may *disappear* after redirect. View/template rendering is also counted, so if you'll redirect the error to new action, forward it in the controller, so redirected view can see it.

Comment: I have actually already considered this solution. However, when you call `badRequest()` (as you should when there is an error in the form), you should not at the same time use flash. In fact, if you do, this produces a warning: _You are using status code '400' with flashing, which should only be used with a redirect status!_. So that's why I decided to use `Http.Context`rather than flash. The idea is the same, however, namely to avoid passing parameters around.

Comment: I have now updated the question with information concerning flash.

Comment: TBH I don't understand what for this warning is generated (BTW. only in DEV mode). Personally  until it works (at least till 2.3.x) I'm gonna to use it for populating simple messages even without redirect. If future versions will disable it - I'll look for other solution :)

Comment: I have tried using flash, and it does indeed give some problems as described in the Google Group you link to. For example, I sometimes see the message "Wrong password" twice in a row, even though I only type a wrong password in the first attempt, whereas the second is successful. In any case, I don't see a reason not to use `Http.Context` instead of flash, since the effect is the same. (But maybe the problems are the same, too? I haven't encountered any problems, but that doesn't mean they aren't there...)

Comment: this approach does not work in scala, do you have any ideas how to make it  work in scala?